Use of "everyone" and "body"
I'm wondering what "everyone" or "body" means in a football context?

Southampton 1-0 Ipswich
Everyone is in the box
waiting for a Leif Davis cross but instead he pulls it back to Sam
Morsy. The captain's shot is blocked though


Wolves 1-2 Newcastle (87 mins)           There are bodies everywhere.
Rayan Ait-Nouri is on the ground after going down without contact
which is always a concern. While a couple of Newcastle players are
treated for cramp. Wolves are preparing two subs.


Watch the football (soccer) match and the meaning should be easier to grasp.

"There are bodies everywhere" is a phrase typically used to describe the scene of a horrific accident with many seriously injured and dead people. A train derailment. An airplane crash. Two tour buses colliding. Bodies are strewn across the ground. So it's a form of (grotesque) exaggeration for effect on the part of the commentator.  Several players are lying on the ground.
Similar exaggeration is found there with everyone.  Not every player is in the box. But nearly everyone is expecting the ball to be crossed and the crowded box reflects that expectation.
Everywhere...everyone.

Can you explain why the commentor uses "everyone" or "body" rather than "player"? Is it a jargon for sports?

I did explain it. The commentator is exaggerating for effect. Please reread the answer since you appear not to have understood it.   It is not sports jargon.

@Shakila Often "bodies" refer to cadavers, in other words "dead bodies". The sports commentator is using a metaphor instead of players to add melodrama to the scene.

Good answer. Bloody metaphors abound in journalism, and not just sport(s) related. I'm sure I've seen metaphors like 'blood everywhere' , 'blood on the carpet', etc, in connection with mass firings e.g. from a sports team, a board of directors, or of members of the UK Prime Minister's cabinet. One of the latter in 1961 was widely called 'The Night of the Long Knives', a repetition of a term first used about the Nazis' killing of most of the SA leadership in 1934. We often say that 'heads should roll', when what we want people to actually lose is their job or rank.

@MichaelHarvey - or even "It's a total massacre out there/here", or "it's total carnage".  Imagine being an English learner and reading those expressions literally. LOL

@BillyKerr - when I was very small (three or so) I must have been a little scamp, and my grandmother took me on her lap and said 'I'm going to murder you!' I jumped down and ran to my mother, shouting 'Granny's going to murder me!'. I was a little put out that both women seemed to think that this was funny. I can still picture it.

There're no special meanings for everyone or body in football.  We've to interpret from context.  Here they both refer to the players: everyone refers to those waiting for the cross; bodies refers to those on the ground.

What's the difference between the two? I'm a bit confused.

Hi @Shakila, Everyone is a pronoun.  It refers to a group of people one by one and is hence singular; bodies is a plural noun. They are different generally and are for different use. Let's use players for the two constructions to see the difference: All the players are in the box...
There are (injured) players everywhere.

Thanks a lot, Seowjooheng

I. Everyone in the box meaning.*

Southampton 1-0 Ipswich.
Everyone is in the box waiting for a Leif Davis cross but instead he pulls it back to Sam Morsy. The captain's shot is blocked though.

Let's check the meanings of the football term.
Ref. Wikipedia.


Cross In association football, a cross is a medium- to-long-range pass from a wide area of the pitch towards the centre of the field near the opponent's goal.
pulls it back : When the player reaches the byline, the player needs to pass or cross the ball. One option is to pull the ball back - this means to pass the ball back towards a teammate instead of crossing the ball sideways towards the goal.
Everyone is in the box : penalty box: The penalty area or 18-yard box (also known less formally as the penalty box or simply box)


So the term "everyone in the box" can be understood easily. It means the players standing in the penalty box. The attacking team trying to score a goal and the defending team trying to prevent the goal.



II. There are bodies everywhere -meaning.

Wolves 1-2 Newcastle (87 mins) There are bodies everywhere. Rayan Ait-Nouri is on the ground after going down without contact which is always a concern. While a couple of Newcastle players are treated for cramp. Wolves are preparing two subs.


Down by contact: When a player with possession of the ball is made to touch the ground (other than hands or feet) by a defensive player; for example, if the ball-carrier slips and falls, he can get up and continue, but if he was pushed by a defensive player, he is said to be down by contact and the play is dead.

But in this case Rayan Alt-Nouri went without contact means he fell down without being pushed. At the same time two Newcastle players were being treated for cramps. Bodies everywhere is an exaggeration and refer to these three players.
